# In SwiftUI, how can I add a video on loop as a fullscreen background image?

Tags: uikit, swiftui

I have a video thats around 10 seconds long that I'd like to play on a loop as a fullscreen background image in one of my SwiftUI Views. How can I implement this?

First idea was working with Swift's `import AVFoundation`, but not sure if this is the right path.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `AV` family of frameworks and `UIViewRepresentable` to do this:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return PlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
    }
}
```

In order for the video to loop I have added  an observer and set the `actionAtItemEnd` to `.none` to support looping.

When the video reaches the end it will execute the `playerItemDidReachEnd(...)` method and seek to the beginning of the video and keep looping.

The example points to a remote video URL. If you want to point to a file within your application you can use `Bundle.main.url` to do so instead:

```
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IMG_2770", withExtension: "MOV") {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)
    // ...
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")!
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        player.play()
        
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                               name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: player.currentItem)

        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }
    
    @objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
        if let playerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
            playerItem.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                PlayerView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers the playing part, but how is it possible to loop the video?

Comment: In my original question title and description I had included asking about the looping part as well 

Comment: @user12533955 Oh yeah you did! Apologies. I've updated the answer to work with looping the video when it reaches the end.

Comment: No worries, works well. My question is, what's the benefit to using NotificationCenter for looping rather than AVPlayerLooper?

Comment: I guess I've always found it quicker to implement `NotificationCenter` rather than `AVPlayerLooper` and your question was around using an activity indicator so it's a blocking implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:
[source](https://schwiftyui.com/swiftui/playing-videos-on-a-loop-in-swiftui/)

```
var body: some View { 
    ZStack{ 
        HStack{
            Spacer()
                .frame(width: 50)
            AmbienceVid()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }       
}


 struct AmbienceVid: UIViewRepresentable {
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AmbienceVid>) {
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
      return PlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
    }
  }


class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?
    private var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame) 
        // Load the resource
        let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ambiencevid", withExtension: "mp4")!
        let asset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        
        // Setup the player
        let player = AVQueuePlayer()
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
         
        // Create a new player looper with the queue player and template item
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)

        // Start the movie
        player.play()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SwiftUI

As someone completely new to swift and for anyone who doesn't want to spend hours debugging this like I did. My use case was trying to create a login screen with a video playing in the background. I was struggling with the looping not working and then with the video stopping after a few seconds and starting again after the duration. This works for me.

Add a new view:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

struct WelcomeVideo: View {
    var body: some View {
        WelcomeVideoController()
    }
}

struct WelcomeVideo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WelcomeVideo()
    }
}

final class WelcomeVideoController : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WelcomeVideoController>) ->
        AVPlayerViewController {
            let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
            
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "welcome", ofType:"mp4") else {
                debugPrint("welcome.mp4 not found")
                return controller
            }
                    
            let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer()
            // OR let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [playerItem]) to pass in items
            
            playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: playerItem)
            queuePlayer.play()
            controller.player = queuePlayer
                
            return controller
        }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WelcomeVideoController>) {
    }
}
```

Then attach it to a view background:

`.background(WelcomeVideo())`

NOTE:

1. Make sure your video is imported to your project
2. Update the name of the video to what you need or refactor slightly to pass it in

Cheers!

Comment: Representables are defined as structs. A Coordinator can store the Looper reference.

Answer (score 2):

A looping, no-controls macOS implementation if people were searching for it.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct NSVideoPlayer: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    var videoURL: URL
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> AVPlayerView {
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL)
        let queue = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: item)
        context.coordinator.looper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queue, templateItem: item)
        
        let view = AVPlayerView()
        view.player = queue
        view.controlsStyle = .none
        view.player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1)
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: AVPlayerView, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator {
        var looper: AVPlayerLooper? = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested in Swift 5 and SwiftUI 3

Viewmodel class functions

```
var avPlayer = AVPlayer()

func previewPlayer() -> AVPlayer {
    self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: vedioData.preWithWithDecoURL!)
    return self.avPlayer
}

func loopCurrentVedio() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
        self.avPlayer.seek(to: .zero)
        self.avPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

In your SwiftUI View class

```
  VideoPlayer(player: previewPlayer())
                .frame(width: 300, height: 532, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .onAppear {
                    loopCurrentVedio()
                }
```

This is the simplest solution I found

Comment: This will show artifacts when seeking back. The proper way to do this (also from a resource perspective) is to user a `AVPlayerLooper`.