# Any way to get a gif as a background with swiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to get a gif to be a background layer of a view but swiftUI doesn't seem to allow that. I've looked through stack overflow and found it is possible to do so through UIKit, but I'm still new to swift in general and not that comfortable with UIKit.
If there is any way to do so with swiftUI, would love for some input.

If a gif isn't possible, maybe an automatic video in the background?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In SwiftUI, how can I add a video on loop as a fullscreen background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937756/in-swiftui-how-can-i-add-a-video-on-loop-as-a-fullscreen-background-image)

Comment: Yeah it looks close enough, I'll give it a shot

Comment: Hi, you can try this SSSwiftUIGIFView (https://github.com/simformsolutions/SSSwiftUIGIFView)

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used a WKWebView to display a gif. The resulting view can be set anywhere. To set it as a background, you'll probably want to resize the contents of the WKWebView according to the contents of the superview.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct HTMLRenderingWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var htmlString: String
    @Binding var baseURL: URL?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if self.htmlString != context.coordinator.lastLoadedHTML {
            print("Updating HTML")
            context.coordinator.lastLoadedHTML = self.htmlString
            uiView.loadHTMLString(self.htmlString, baseURL: self.baseURL)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: HTMLRenderingWebView
        var lastLoadedHTML = ""

        init(_ parent: HTMLRenderingWebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}

struct HTMLRenderingWebViewExample: View {
    @State var htmlString = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HTMLRenderingWebView(htmlString: self.$htmlString, baseURL: .constant(nil))
                .padding(30).background(Color.gray)
            Button("Click this button") {
                self.htmlString = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />" +
                    (self.assetAsString() ?? "image loading failed")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Example HTML Rendering")
    }

    func assetAsString() -> String? {
        let asset = NSDataAsset(name: "User_OhSqueezy_on_commons_wikimedia_org_Parallax_scrolling_example_scene")
        if let data = asset?.data {
            let base64string = data.base64EncodedString()
            let format = "gif"
            return "<img src='data:image/\(format);base64," + base64string + "' height=240 width=360>"
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I got my animated gif from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parallax_scrolling_example_scene.gif) and dragged it into the `Assets.xcassets` in Xcode.

Result:
[image: Animated gif of Xcode Simulator showing animated gif]